# UICollectionViewCell not clickable after i add a subview to it

Tags: xcode, uicollectionview

I am using a collection view with custom cells. I don't know why but my cells stopped working (they don't call didSelect anymore).

Basically it's a simple cell that i'm just putting a view on top of it (addSubview).
This view contains two imageViews and two labels.

I noticed that when i don't add this view, they do call didSelect. Isn't there a way to add a view on a UITableViewCell?

This is the code i'm using to add the view:

```
- (void)setCellWithMediaView:(TVNCategoryWideAndTallMediaView *)mediaView {

    if (self.contentView.subviews.count > 0) {
        [[self.contentView.subviews lastObject] removeFromSuperview];
    }

    self.categoryWideAndTallMediaView = [[TVNCategoryWideAndTallMediaView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
    self.categoryWideAndTallMediaView = mediaView;
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.categoryWideAndTallMediaView];

    self.isMediaSet = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `userInteractionEnabled` property to `NO` for that view and subviews.

```
self.categoryWideAndTallMediaView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```